# entry_id_path not working

Tags: channel-entries, cartthrob

I'm using the following code:

```
<a href="{entry_id_path='shop/add_to_cart_template'}">link text</a>
```

However, when the browser renders the page it's generating a bogus link...

```
http://domain.com/%7Bentry_id_path='shop/add_to_cart_template'%7D
```

Anyone know why it would be outputting that code?

Comment: Is your code properly within an `{exp:channel:entries}` pair?

Comment: I can't remember exactly how, but I solved this problem. June 17 was so long ago. :)

Thanks anyways!